# Let $Z$ be standard normal, let $N$ have distribution given by $P(N=1)=P(N=2)=1/2$. Compute $P(N=1 \mid Z^N=1)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable and let $N$ have distribution given by $P(N=$ 1) $=P(N=2)=1 / 2$ with $N$ and $Z$ independent. Set $X=Z^{N}$. Compute $P(N=1 \mid X=1)$.

---

Here's my attempt:

\begin{aligned}
P(N=1 \mid X=1) &=\frac{P(X=1 \mid N=1) P(N=1)}{P(X=1)} \\
&=\frac{P\left(Z^{N}=1 \mid N=1\right) P(N=1)}{P\left(Z^{N}=1\right)} \\
&=\frac{P(Z=1) P(N=1)}{P\left(Z^{N}=1 \mid N=1\right) P(N=1)+P\left(Z^{N}=1 \mid N=2\right) P(N=2)} \\
&=\frac{P(Z=1) P(N=1)}{\frac{1}{2} P(Z=1)+\frac{1}{2} P\left(Z^{2}=1\right)} \\
&=\frac{P(Z=1) P(N=1)}{P(Z=1)} \\
&=P(N=1) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}

---

However, the solutions to this problem give a different approach that's a bit more vague and I don't really understand what's going on. I still seem to get the same answer though, I don't know if that's a fluke or if my way is correct as well:

The solution is given by
$$
\frac{f_{N, X}(1,1)}{f_{X}(1)}
$$
where $f_{N, X}$ is the joint $\mathrm{pmf} / \mathrm{pdf}$ of $(N, X)$ and $f_{X}$ is the marginal pdf of $X .$ The joint pmf/pdf satisfies
$$
f_{N, X}(n, 1)=f_{X \mid N}(1 \mid n) P(N=n)
$$
Given $N=1, X=Z$ is standard normal and given $N=2, X=Z^{2}$ has density, for $x>0$
$$
\frac{d}{d x} P\left(Z^{2} \leq x\right)=\frac{d}{d x}(1-2 P(Z>\sqrt{x}))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} x^{-1 / 2} e^{-x / 2}
$$
Therefore, $f_{N, X}(1,1)=\frac{e^{-1 / 2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, and
$$
f_{X}(1)=\left(f_{N, X}(1,1)+f_{N, X}(2,1)\right)=\frac{e^{-1 / 2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}
$$
and so $P(N=1 \mid X=1)=1 / 2$

---

My question is, how did they get this solution? Why do they seem to only consider the density of $Z^2$ and not $Z$? And is my solution correct as well, or is there an error in reasoning there? Thank you.

Comment: "density of $^2$ and not $$". If you were to integrate both distributions, you would realise that in order for $Z^2$ to be integrated, you would need to integrate $Z$ as the inner function (using integration by parts) $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{Z^2}$$ Therefore, technically speaking, $$\int^{a}_{b}{Z} \in \int^{a}_{b}{Z^2}$$ This means you are automatically considering the density of $Z$ by integrating $Z^2$.

Comment: Doesn't $Z^N=1$ have probability $0$?